# Printing JasperReport From Applet

Tags: java, applet, jasper-reports

I have developed web application which uses `JasperReports` for reporting purpose.
In that I have to use Applet to View report at Client side. I can see report in applet normally , but when it comes to printing (when i clicked on Print Button in Viewer), it throws an Exception which I can see in Java Console. I surfed lots of about this Problem and did whatever which are suggested by experts on the net. I added the grant permission in `catalina.policy` file as I uses the `Tomcat` as my web server. Also, added grant permission to my applet as a codebase in `java.policy` file. I signed the jar file which has class file for an Applet. But I still getting the same error.

below is the stack trace from Java console .

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_24
Using JRE version 1.6.0_24-b07 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator


Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer$21.run(JRViewer.java:1211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.print)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.<clinit>(JasperPrintManager.java:419)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to allow an applet to print you need to sign the applet:

[Signing and Verifying JAR Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html)

[Signing Your Applet](http://www.qoppa.com/faq/signapplet.htm)

Comment: Thank You for your quick reply. I have already done it . and also set policy files , catalina and java . still i got the exception.

Comment: another question is if we sign the Applet and Jar Files then is is necessary to change policy files ?

Comment: in order to permission for Running an Applet i get additional dialog with message which screen shot i attached here.

Comment: I can not attach jar files here , so i am writing the consequence of the dialog that "The Applet Contains Signed and Unsigned code , it may be harmful to your computer ".

Comment: i found the solution.I am using 5 jar files and i signed the one which has my applet class, that's why i am getting the error . so i signed all the jars and now i can print from the applet.  Thank You very much stacker .